# Function is undefined when I call on it in the console or an array, but works within another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

So I'm writing a program in JavaScript in which several of the values within an array are dependent on the outcome of a function. This function is used elsewhere in the code as well, and works fine there.

The code looks something like this:

```
var Multiplier; 
$("#button").on("click", function() { foo(); });

function foo() {
    x = document.getElementById("select").value;
    setMultiplier(x);
    setName(x);
    $("#select").hide();
    $("#page").show();
}
function setMultiplier(q) {
    if (q === "Option 1") {
        Multiplier = 1;
        return Multiplier;
    } else if (q === "Option 2") {
        Multiplier = 100;
        return Multiplier;
    }
}
function mult(base) {
    var z;
    z = base * Multiplier;
    return z;
}
```

The problem I am having has nothing to do with the `setName()` as far as I can tell, because that function works fine. Also, `Multiplier` has the proper value elsewhere. However, when it is used within an array found later in the program, it gives a value of `undefined` and when I type it into the console it also says `Multiplier is not defined`. The same thing happens with the `mult()` function both in the array and in the console, but it works fine elsewhere. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**
So later in the program, `mult(base)` is called upon in two types of contexts:
1. Within a function (which works) like so:

```
function blah() {
    var s = "<div>$" + mult(75) + "</div>";
    s += "<div>$" + mult(150) + "</div>";
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = s;
}
```

2. Within an array (which doesn't work) like so:

```
var array = [["String1", mult(60), 0, [mult(2), mult(5)], mult(30)], 
["String2", mult(100), 0, [mult(10), mult(25)], mult(50)]];
```

Comment: Are all your function nested inside each other ?

Comment: `var Multiplier;` needs to be in the outermost scope for it to be a global variable, in case it isn't already.

Comment: The `mult` function is local to the `setMultiplier` function, so it can't be referenced outside. If you want to access it from other scopes, don't nest it inside another function definition.

Comment: They are separate functions. I guess they just got indented weirdly. I also have to fix curly brackets. My mistake on that one.

Comment: Without any more context it's going to be difficult to help, I think.

Comment: It can't not work if that function is currently loaded into the browser and is in an appropriate scope. My initial concern would be that those functions are being defined in a jQuery domReady function, meaning they're not in global scope.

Comment: @Dave Newton I tried that, but when I removed it from the domReady function it stopped working altogether rather than just giving me `NaN` as a result. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/b0rrbsod/) is a jsfiddle with the full program.

Comment: If everything that refers to that function/those functions is inside the domReady function then there can't really be an issue. If it's defined in the domReady function, however, it will not be available anywhere else (e.g., the console).

Comment: But what I don't understand is why it isn't able to be used within the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, and you are.

The issue is that you initialize `properties` with `mult()` calls only once, at the time you declare `properties`. `TemplateName` is only initialized after someone makes clicky on the UI: *before* it's initialized its value is `null`, which doesn't play nice with numbers.

JS won't magically go back and re-initialize `properties`, or re-run `mult` every time you access on of its value: when you declare `properties` and set all those values it's doing it with whatever `mult` returns at the time `properties` is declared.